# Find a basis for the Eigenspace associated with λ for each given matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Matrix A is 
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
      5 & 0 & 0\\
      2 & 5 & 2\\
      -2 & 0 & 3\\
      \end{pmatrix}$$
$$ \lambda = 5$$

I used $$(A - \lambda I)$$ to find the basis.

This is what I got:
$$A= \begin{pmatrix}
     0 & 0 & 0\\
     2 & 0 & 2\\
     -2 & 0 & -2\\
     \end{pmatrix} $$ and the rref of that is:
$$rref(A)= \begin{pmatrix}
           1 & 0 & 1\\         
           0 & 0 & 0\\
           0 & 0 & 0\\
           \end{pmatrix}$$
Shouldn't the basis be: $$ \begin{pmatrix}
                           -1\\                           
                            0\\
                            0\\
                           \end{pmatrix}$$
But it says that my answer is wrong, I don't know where I went wrong. Can someone please explain.

Comment: How did you come up with $(-1,0,0)^t?$

Comment: [1,0,1] scalar product something should be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $v=\begin{pmatrix} x \\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector for $\lambda$ then $(A-\lambda I)v=0$. Using the rref form of this $A-\lambda I$ should get$$ \begin{pmatrix}
           1 & 0 & 1\\         
           0 & 0 & 0\\
           0 & 0 & 0\\
           \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\y\\z\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}  0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$ which gives $x+z=0$ or $x=-z$. Therefore such vector $v$ can be written as $$v=\begin{pmatrix} x \\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -z\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=y\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\1\\0\end{pmatrix}+z\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\0\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$ So the vectors $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ span the eigenspace of $\lambda$. It is also clearly linearly independent. Therefore the basis for eigenspace is the vectors $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 3):

Your basis $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$ must satisfy three things:

1. $\{v_i\}_i$ is linearly independent
2. $Av = 0$ for all basis vectors $v$
3. $|I| = n - \mathrm{rank}(A)$

The third point means $|I| = 3 - 1 = 2$, so you need two basis vectors.
Point 2 rewrites to
$$x_1 + x_3 = 0$$
i.e. $x_3 = -x_1$, $x_2$ is free.

An elegant choice of basis is thus
$$v_1 = \pmatrix{1\\0\\-1}, \quad v_2 = \pmatrix{0\\1\\0}$$

We can see linear independence easily and checking 2. should be easy as well (Confirm that $Av_1 = Av_2 = 0$). Finally, since the rank of $A$ is 1, there can not be a third such vector. Else, the basis would span a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ with dimension $3$. The only such subspace is $\mathbb R^3$ itself and that would imply $A=0$.